# Query for nearest date login to current date for every user

Tags: mysql

I want to ask for a sample query i can use to know the the most current login date of each for my user... **thanks**

```
+----+---------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| id | version | first_name | last_name | login_detail        |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 |       0 | Mark       | Yap2      | 2013-02-01 16:00:23 |
|  2 |       0 | Mark       | Yap2      | 2013-02-01 16:00:38 |
|  3 |       0 | Mark       | Yap2      | 2013-02-04 13:38:41 |
|  4 |       0 | john       | doe       | 2013-02-04 13:50:39 |
|  5 |       0 | Mark       | Yap2      | 2013-02-04 13:59:01 |
|  6 |       0 | Mark       | Yap2      | 2013-02-04 14:04:25 |
|  7 |       0 | john       | doe       | 2013-02-04 14:09:47 |
|  8 |       0 | Mark       | Yap2      | 2013-02-04 14:14:40 |
|  9 |       0 | Mark       | Yap2      | 2013-02-04 14:15:36 |
| 10 |       0 | john       | doe       | 2013-02-04 14:16:11 |
| 11 |       0 | Mark       | Yap2      | 2013-02-04 14:23:38 |
| 12 |       0 | john       | doe       | 2013-02-04 14:26:53 |
| 13 |       0 | john       | doe       | 2013-02-04 15:50:45 |
| 14 |       0 | john       | doe       | 2013-02-04 15:55:53 |
| 15 |       0 | john       | doe       | 2013-02-04 15:59:15 |
| 16 |       0 | john       | doe       | 2013-02-04 16:05:15 |
| 17 |       0 | john       | doe       | 2013-02-04 16:09:54 |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

for this sample table...
i want to get the latest login record for each user...
which are the ones with id 17 and 11 for the 2 different users

Comment: Can the 'current' date be in the past? Or are you just looking for the most recent login date for each user?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table named `tableName`, and has columns: `userID`, `last_login`. You can know the most current login date of the user by using `MAX` which is an *Aggregate Function*.

```
SELECT userID, 
       MAX(last_login) most_current_login
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY userID
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. it only prints 1 user.... my fields are lastname firstname and login(time/date)

Comment: can you give swample records with desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEexample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d376c/1)**

```
SELECT first_name, 
       last_name,
       MAX(login_detail) latest_login_record
FROM   Table1
GROUP  BY first_name, 
          last_name
```

Result:

```
| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |             LATEST_LOGIN_RECORD |
------------------------------------------------------------
|       john |       doe | February, 04 2013 16:09:54+0000 |
|       Mark |      Yap2 | February, 04 2013 14:23:38+0000 |
```